# TFS Build Agent Run .bat File After Build

Tags: .net, tfs, build, continuous-integration

I'm confused by a lot of the documentation about TFS build agents.

I'm trying to do something like this (https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler#setup-a-bundler-runner) the option after step 3. TLDR; Run a .bat file from a CI build agent.

How do I specify to a build agent to run a .bat file?

Answer (score 2):

With TFS you either modify the build template (workflow xaml file) which can be painful if you've never done it before.

Or you can include an Exec Task in your csproj (or other project types) MSBuild that will in turn be called by TFS Build.

Or if you're using TFS 2013 there are hooks in the new default 2013 build template that allow you to specify a powershell file to run from the build definition.

Comment: Can you guide me to where I should place this Exec Task in the project?